# Auto height rectangle in detail band

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *iReport*. I want to know how to make an auto height rectangle?[image]

as per this sample image of detail band. There is two part one is data part on right side which fetch data and show. and left side part is a textarea data which is passed as parameter.
I want to make both rectangle same height. It may possible that left side data height is bigger than right side part and vice versa. So I want to make both rectangle height same all the time.

For achieving this i use following code. where I don't use rectangles but a lines only

```xml
<columnHeader>
            <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="28" width="555" height="1" uuid="9d2cb019-77f2-47a0-94f7-aa944b5c277e"/>
        </line>
    </band>
</columnHeader>

    <detail>
    <band height="13" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="472" y="0" width="50" height="13" uuid="4b51d986-b6f9-45e2-a151-e9d7f86007f3"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{packing}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="526" y="0" width="27" height="13" uuid="930cf91c-710a-40c4-a899-fde5ddfd7ce4"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sli_pack}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="471" y="0" width="1" height="13" uuid="434d1954-3286-4539-a3d9-915f28364210"/>
        </line>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="555" y="-1" width="1" height="13" uuid="39dab81d-1bb3-41bd-8fff-9780b7f65672"/>
        </line>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="-1" width="1" height="13" uuid="8936db56-872f-434d-a39b-298ffdb99e57"/>
        </line>
    </band>
</detail>
<summary>
    <band height="1" splitType="Stretch">
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="-1" width="555" height="1" uuid="ba7dbcc7-fd20-4ee9-b593-480737f9b88c"/>
        </line>
    </band>
</summary>
```

But the issue with this way is corners of rectangle is not properly printed.

My questions are:

1) Is there any better way to do this?

2) how to draw a border of complete detail band?

3) How to do this with rectangle ?

Here is another try with rectangle around detail band but rectangle is repeated to each row.

```
<detail>
    <band height="13" splitType="Stretch">
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="1" y="0" width="552" height="13" uuid="80b946be-ac5f-495d-a507-fec3e22ea751"/>
        </rectangle>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="465" y="0" width="50" height="13" uuid="4b51d986-b6f9-45e2-a151-e9d7f86007f3"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{packing}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="526" y="0" width="27" height="13" uuid="930cf91c-710a-40c4-a899-fde5ddfd7ce4"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sli_pack}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think you can find the answer in their documentation in this Link:
https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/dynamically-set-table-row-height-data

To sum up here are the options you should enable.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you should have one rectangle and place a line in between. Use the property of line, check stretchWithOverflow to true. Simillarly with rectangle.

Comment: where should I put rectangle? in detail band? I tried first but it repeat with each recoreds

Comment: Rectangle repeat for each row

Comment: Is the xml same as the one you have posted? If not post the one which has repeating rectangle.

Comment: How are you passing the data to the report?

Comment: right side data is as a parameter and left side data is fetch from mysql.

Comment: You have to pass both the things into datasource. Try doing that.

Answer (score -1):

First select your field and set following properties (**third one** is most important):

1. Position type: `float`
2. `Stretch` type: relative to tallest object
3. `Stretch` with overflow: `true` (checked)